# Term for diagonalizing matrix into multiple diagonal matrices?

Tags: matrices, diagonalization

Is there a term for diagonalizing a matrix into more than one diagonal matrix? Or is this also just considered as a standard diagonalization problem?

So for example writing a matrix $L$ as $ L = A\times D_1\times B\times D_2 \times C$ where $D_1$ and $D_2$ are diagonal matrices.

Comment: I don't believe doing this is standard in any part of linear algebra, so there's probably no name for it. Why would you want to have multiple diagonal matrices if you can also have a Jordan canonical form?

Comment: @student91 Because in the PARATUCK2 decomposition for 3-way tensors every frontal slice of the tensor is decomposed in the form containing the two diagonal matrices mentioned above. Hence I was curious if there was any equivalent term to refer to diagonalization into 2 matrices.